# Problem with iterating over database in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning programming and I am stuck on something. would be great if someone can point me what am doing wrong. I wanted to write a small program to do the following:

- **Ask the user to enter his position, userid and password and press ENTER.**
- **Connect to database and look into "account_tbl" where those credentials are stored**.
- validate the credentials
- **Give the user three chances**
- **Kick user out after three trials**

I have managed to perform everything point in bold. It seems that the logic for validating the password is not correct. The validation work only if I enter the credentials in the same sequence I stored the account in the database. Below is a copy of the table.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDS1E.png)

In my example I will use the last account in the table and look what happened.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c77c.png)

Find below a copy of my code:

```
import sqlite3

connect_fworlddb = sqlite3.connect('fworld.db')
myCursor = connect_fworlddb.cursor()
myCursor.execute('SELECT * FROM account_tbl')
allusers = myCursor.fetchall()

for chances in range(3,0,-1):

    xrole = input("Enter your Role: ")
    xuserid = input("Enter your UserID: ")
    xpassword = input("Enter your Password: ")

    for user in allusers:
        print(user) #i have added this part to print what's happening
        if user[2]==xrole and  user[0]==xuserid and user[1]==xpassword in user:
            print("Found")
            break
        else:
            print("Not Found")
if chances == 1:
    print("User" + " " + xuserid + " " + "account has been locked.")
    print("Please contact the system Administrator on ext. 5408")
```

Comment: `user[1]==xpassword in user` seems off. What's your intent there?

Comment: when looping over the database it return a tuple as shown in the screen shot. I wanted to loop over the tuple and check if password entered is the same.

Comment: This isn't working for you though because when you `break`, you're only breaking from the inner for loop, not the outer one. You'd need to put this is a method and return or something to break out of both loops at once.